# how to get predefined HTML tags in sublime text2

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, text-editor

Is there any package available that can do the following:

1.When I create a new html file:I should get the predefined text like this(eg.dreamweaver,phpstorm)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body></body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something with a few more keystrokes could be the File Template package? [The demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4isYen7_Z4) looks simple enough.

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5428